Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "" al ejecutar código
Donde deriva el error según me aparece ahí es en este bloque de código
void guardarDetalle(){
        String idv=vdao.IdVentas();
        int idva=Integer.parseInt(idv);
         for (int i = 0; i <tablaVentas.getRowCount(); i++) {
             int idp=Integer.parseInt(tablaVentas.getValueAt(i,1).toString());
             int cant=Integer.parseInt(tablaVentas.getValueAt(i,3).toString());
             double pre=Double.parseDouble(tablaVentas.getValueAt(i,4).toString());
             dv.setIdVentas(idva);
             dv.setIdProducto(idp);
             dv.setCantidad(cant);
             dv.setPreVenta(pre);
             vdao.GuardarDetalleVentas(dv);
             
         }
    }

y al ejecutar me aparece este error

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:672)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:778)
at vistas.VentasForm.guardarDetalle(VentasForm.java:484)
at vistas.VentasForm.btnVentaActionPerformed(VentasForm.java:439)
at vistas.VentasForm$10.actionPerformed(VentasForm.java:348)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2314)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:407)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6621)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3398)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6386)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4996)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4828)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2780)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4828)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:775)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:714)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:98)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:747)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:744)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)


Estás intentando convertir un string vacío en un número. Qué valor debería tener eso?? 0? infinito? 42? Comprueba que los string no están vacíos antes de parsearlos, y si lo están simplemente añade tú el número que quieras / tenga sentido para tu lógica. Recuerda que investigar antes de preguntar es necesario. Una simple búsqueda en google de java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "" te da exactamente el problema y la solución... Si quieres aprender a programar, debes aprender a buscar los errores al menos.

Además de lo que te han mencionado, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Presta atención a las ediciones a tu pregunta; el título debe describir brevemente qué problema estás teniendo.

¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? Por que me sale este error java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Te sugiero hacer un validador de columna primero:
for (int i = 0; i <tablaVentas.getRowCount(); i++) {
       if(tablaVentas.getValueAt(i,1).toString().equals("")){
            tablaVentas.setValueAt(0,i,1);
       }
}

